# Ejabberd + Bandersnatch Presence table not being updated

Tags: ejabberd

I have setup bandersnatch + ejabberd 2.1.6, I found it only can record the message into the message table,the user and presence tables stay empty. Do I need to do some extra configuration to set that up?

Thank you

Comment: more appropriate for http://serverfault.com .  Also in future postings there relevant sections of config files are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd don't support presence management in DB

Comment: Can you please explain it more? Do you have some alternatives or ideas how to solve?